# Filling foreign key values of a table through loop

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to copy data from one table to another schema. But while copying the content I am struggling to fill foreign key values in the second database. Let's say the table (from which I'm trying to copy the data) is-

Sample_

| v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 'A1' | 'B2' |
| 2 | 6 | 'A1' | 'B1' |
| 3 | 7 | 'A1' | 'B2' |
| 4 | 8 | 'A2' | 'B2' |

Now, I have created another schema which has 3 tables:

main_

| idx | v1 | v2 | v3_id | v4_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

V3_

| v3_id | v3 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'A1' |
| 2 | 'A2' |

V4_

| v4_id | v4 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'B1' |
| 2 | 'B2' |

I have filled V3_, and V4_ but I haven't been able to fill main_ because of an error. I'm using loop to fill the values. I have ran the following code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ROWPERROW()
BEGIN
    DECLARE n INTEGER DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE i INTEGER DEFAULT NULL;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sample_ INTO n;
    SET i=0;
    WHILE i<n DO
      INSERT INTO main_(v1, v2) SELECT (v1, v2) FROM sample_ LIMIT i,1;
      INSERT INTO main_(v3) SELECT v3_id FROM V3_ WHERE V3_.v3=SELECT v3 FROM sample_ LIMIT i, 1;
      INSERT INTO main_(v4) SELECT v4_id FROM V4_ WHERE V4_.v4=SELECT v4 FROM sample_ LIMIT i, 1;
      SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
End;
;;
```

Error message:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT v3 FROM sample_ LIMIT i, 1;
INSERT INTO main_(v4) SELECT v4_id FRO' at line 9

I don't understand why it is showing syntax error. Also, is there a better way to copy data from a one schema to another?

I want main_ to look like this-

main_

| idx | v1 | v2 | v3_id | v4_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 6 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 7 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 8 | 2 | 2 |

Comment: WHERE V3_.v3=SELECT v3 FROM - is invalid only 1 select allowed - you could bracket the second select and that would be syntactically fine.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for replying. I tried your suggestion. Now, it's not showing the error. However, it is returning an empty result set. Could you suggest what I'm doing wrong in it?

Comment: Please add what you expect main to look like after all insert based on sample.

Comment: I have updated it in the question.

Comment: There a number errors in the code to be fixed before addressing logic issues

SELECT (v1, v2) throws an error v1,v2 should not be bracketed

INSERT INTO main_(v3) - there is no v3 column in main

INSERT INTO main_(v4) - there is no v4 column in main

Comment: BTW the first insert if run on it;s own after correction does populate main_ after that I can't see what goes where..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping, I was able to find another solution. I am sharing it below-
`INSERT INTO main_ (v1, v2, v3_id, v4_id) SELECT v1, v2, v3_id, v4_id FROM (SELECT v1, v2, v3_id, v4_id FROM (SELECT v1, v2, v3_id, v4 FROM sample_ INNER JOIN V3_ ON sample_.v3 = V3_.v3) AS new INNER JOIN V4_ ON new.v4 = V4_.v4) as new1;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).